# In which single word can this be summarized?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms, descriptive-grammar

Say you have several companies working for you to achieve/complete a certain task, but the one who does best/finishes the job gets the commission for the job. I'm aware of the term `pitch` (from the elevator pitch) but I'm looking for synonyms or alternative words to describe this type of behavior/scenario.

Even better; if there's a name for this and was described by someone in history I'd like to read about it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Those companies are **vying** for the commission.

Comment: In a selection process, the buyer first issues a "call for tender". Each interested companies submits a "bid" (i.e. a proposal with technical response and price declaration). Then, the buyer selects the "best offer" and commissions the winner. To what part of this process do you refer.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think any companies are working for you unless they are paid for the work. They are just preparing for [competition](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/competition) or a ***bid*** (bidding) process where competition to get a contract (commission) is going on.

The noun [***bid***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/bid) means:

> An offer to do work or supply goods at a stated price; a tender: *a
>   number of businessmen were keen to make a bid for the £75 million
>   contract*

You can use the verb ***bid*** to say:

> They are preparing to bid for the contract (work).

You could visit the link in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bidding) explaining about *bidding*.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for ***tender***:

> - Unconditional offer of money (to satisfy a debt) or performance (to satisfy an obligation).

Comment: That definition is more relevant to the synonym *payment*. Look at this instead: http://www.investopedia.com/terms/t/tender.asp .